# How get value from ChannelBox in Maya looped?

Tags: python, maya, mel

I want get input nodes from ChannelBox, but when i used "for in" or "while" loop, it return inputs from last selected object.

I have these objects and inputs:

> Object1 [u'Input1', u'tweak1']
> Object2 [u'Input2', u'tweak2']

```
from maya.cmds import *

AFM_selObjs = ls (sl = True)
for AFM_selObj in AFM_selObjs:
     print (AFM_selObj)
     AFM_listHistories = channelBox ('mainChannelBox', q = True, inputs = True)
     print (AFM_listHistories)
```

But this codes return these wrong values:

> Object1 [u'Input2', u'tweak2']
> Object2 [u'Input2', u'tweak2']

Comment: https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/107799/maya.cmds.channelBox

Comment: @Selman thanks. but this isn't useful.

Comment: Yes, seems that the channelbox UI command does not correctly work in a loop. If you want to get the inputs of the selected nodes, it could be helpful to get it directly with something like `listHistory()`.